# Extract only a portion of a string within a list without modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with several text items in it. Some of these items have URLs and I want to extract only these URLs.

```
my_list = ['ok', 'thanks, here we go: https://www.example.com', 'http://example.org']
```

I want to show just the URL, for example:

```
my_new_list = ['https://example.com', 'http://example.org']
```

I managed to create a `for` loop to show only the items that have a URL, but the return still brings the rest of the text inside the list. For example `my_new_list = ['thanks, here we go: https://www.example.com']`

Edit: Clarify that I want to do that without modules.

Comment: Maybe you can use ```re``` module for regex

Comment: What's your exact syntactic definition of a url?

Comment: @RenéPijl Something that contains 'http' would work in this case for me

Comment: I would like to know how to do this without any modules. I wrote "libraries" but I mean "module". How to do this without import regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `regex` you can do the following:

```py
import re
my_list = ['ok', 'thanks, here we go: https://www.example.com', 'http://example.org']
final_list = []
for my_string in my_list:
    final_list += re.findall(r'(?i)\b((?:https?:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)/)(?:[^\s()<>{}\[\]]+|\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\))+(?:\([^\s()]*?\([^\s()]+\)[^\s()]*?\)|\([^\s]+?\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’])|(?:(?<!@)[a-z0-9]+(?:[.\-][a-z0-9]+)*[.](?:com|net|org|edu|gov|mil|aero|asia|biz|cat|coop|info|int|jobs|mobi|museum|name|post|pro|tel|travel|xxx|ac|ad|ae|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|as|at|au|aw|ax|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|dd|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gg|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|im|in|io|iq|ir|is|it|je|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|nc|ne|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nu|nz|om|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|rs|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|Ja|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|ss|st|su|sv|sx|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tl|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)\b/?(?!@)))", my_string)

print(final_list)
```

which gives you `['https://www.example.com', 'http://example.org']`. The regex pattern is from [here](https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611).

But since you specified you don't want to use any modules, you can do the following:

```py
my_list = ['ok', 'thanks, here we go: https://www.example.com', 'http://example.org']
final_list = []
for my_string in my_list:
    if 'http' in my_string:
        final_list.append(my_string[my_string.find('http'):])

print(final_list)
```

which finds the index of http in each string (if it's there) and gets the text to the right of it. If it is not guaranteed that the website is at the end of each string you can modify the code as follows:

```py
my_list = ['ok', 'thanks, here we go: https://www.example.com', 'http://example.org is a great website']
final_list = []
for my_string in my_list:
    if 'http' in my_string:
        final_list.append(my_string[my_string.find('http'):].split()[0])

print(final_list)
```

which gives you the same output:

```
['https://www.example.com', 'http://example.org']
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative instead of re with list comprehensions:

```
for j in [element for element in my_list if "http" in element]:
    [print(k) for k in j.split(" ") if k.startswith("http")]
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com
http://example.org
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your answer. Could you explain to me the logic behind it? Why this part is between brackets? `[element for element in my_list if "http" in element]`

Comment: With this syntax the result is a list of elements which have the string "http".
Next step is to iterate over this list to extract only the url part of the string. 

Here you find further examples and explanations of list comprehensions:
[link](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html).
If the answer helped you, feel free to give me an upvote.